# UDP vs TCP protocols

Tags: arduino, communication

What is the difference between TCP and UDP protocols?

I am trying to make a communication between Arduino and a computer. The guys making this with TCP use Arduino as a web-server. The others using UDP are sending UDP packets to Arduino.

What is the difference in their mechanism?

Comment: ummmm... stream-oriented vs. message-oriented?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970383/difference-between-tcp-and-udp

Comment: Duplicate from a different site?  I dunno I think I'd let it pass.

Comment: This has nothing to do with eletronics. However, briefly, UDP is just raw sending packets. They may not always get to the other end, and they may be received out of order. TCP uses ACKs, NACKs, and other handshaking to present a reliable order-preserved stream of bytes to the application level while using individual IP packets underneath. See RFCs 768 (UDP) and 793 (TCP) where this is all described in detail.

Comment: This site is for embedded development in addition to electronics. Definitely not off-topic.

Comment: @AngryEE - the question asks the difference between two communication protocols, which is roughly equivalent to asking 'how should I structure my application'. The same electronics that handle the one will handle the other. A good portion of the network stack that supports one will support the other. It's as nearly off topic as asking the difference between C and C++

Comment: I know a good joke about UDP, but I'm not sure if you'll get it.

Comment: A lot of embedded devices have to deal with networking issues.  If one is designing embedded devices which will use networking modules which support both modes, it can be useful to know the pros and cons of each.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TCP and UDP are protocols on top of the IP layer.  This I'm sure you're aware of.  TCP and UDP differ in the strategies they use to get data to the application.

TCP is a connection-oriented protocol. When the two sides connect, they exchange a sequence number and start counting bytes sent back and forth. All bytes sent back and forth are counted within the sequence number.  So one side can say "I believe I sent you bytes 20-40 in that last packet, can you confirm that you received those bytes in that packet?" This allows each side to know if data wasn't received or was received out of order, and parts of the protocol specify how each side rectifies the situation (ie, with re-requests for certain packets).  There are timeouts as well that determine whether the connection has become interrupted.  If a connection is lost like this, a new session has to be re-negotiated and the sequential count starts over (but not necessarily from byte 0 - a certain amount of randomness is required to prevent some attacks).  Practically this means that a connection like this can't just be picked up again once it becomes interrupted - you have to re-establish the connection.  There are also flow-control features that ensure data isn't sent too fast for one side to process. TCP is very useful where the data absolutely must get through despite delays.

UDP is different.  There is no connection, no sequential numbers, no timeouts.  Packets are sent between the two sides with no other necessary information.  Since there is no connection the packets can be sent at any time.  There's also no guarantee that data gets through. If you send a packet, it may not get there and you'd never know.  Typically, the data is sent with checksums, sequence numbers and such into the data you send if it's necessary for a more secure link.  Because of the lack of timeouts and retries it's much faster than TCP.  Typically UDP is used for situations where speed is more important that getting all of the data.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "session number" in TCP. Individual TCP connections are identified only by their IP addresses and port numbers at each end.  Also, TCP packets don't have a sequential count, bytes do.

Comment: Good to know.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Have you actually read the TCP and UDP specs?  It seems not.  If you haven't, how do you really know what's going on?  Should you really be trying to give authorotative sounding answers on topics you where you haven't even read the basic specs?

Comment: @OlinLathrop I hold your opinion in high esteem.  Should I delete my answer?

Comment: No, at this point what you are saying isn't wrong, which is also why I didn't downvote it. It just seems strange to pontificate on something based on information gathered from heresay instead of first hand knowledge.  In any case, I think this question will be closed soon.

Answer (score 1):

When data is sent via UDP, one of two things will happen: either a packet will reach its destination within a moderately-short time, or it won't.  The sender will be notified that the packet was started on its journey, whether or not it actually reached its destination.  If the packet is not delivered successfully, the receiver will never know of its existence.  It's important to note that while UDP will generally deliver packets in reasonably-timely fashion, there is no guarantee that packets will reach their destination in the order they were sent.  Most of the time they will, but some networking equipment may arbitrarily divide up the packets going through them among several different links, some of which might be slightly faster than others.

TCP, unlike UDP, establishes a connection between two parties and attempts to ensure that all information supplied by each side is received by the other, in the order that it was transmitted; it guarantees that either every byte will be delivered in sequence, or the connection will be declared invalid.  The simplest way to think of TCP is as having nodes send messages of the following format:

```
  I have received information up to but not including your byte #1253, ...
  ... and my data, starting at byte #4381, is "QUACK".
```

Each node sends a message of the above format when either it has data that the other node has not acknowledged, or when it has received data that it has not yet acknowledged.  One very nice thing about TCP is that it doesn't matter too much if an acknowledgment gets lost.  If data is received successfully but the transmitter doesn't know about it, the transmitter will include redundant data the next time it decides to transmit, but the receiver will simply ignore that redundant data and acknowledge all the useful data it received.

A few things to note about TCP:

1. A device which transmits information will expect an acknowledge, and will attempt retransmission if it doesn't get one.  If it persistently fails to get an acknowledge, it will decide the connection is dead, but the other party to the connection may never know about it.

   TCP generally only sends packets when at least one party to the communication has "something to say".  If neither node has anything to say, a TCP connection could sit idle for hours or days without any data flowing through.

   Some TCP implementations will, if no data flows for an extended period of type (often somewhere between a minute and an hour), resend their last byte of data in what's called a "keepalive" packet, "pretending" that they didn't receive an acknowledge for it.  In the normal chain of events, the receiver will know that it already received that byte, and thus discard it, but the will also know that the transmitter is probably expecting an acknowledgment for it.  If the transmitter that sent the "keepalive" doesn't get a response, it will know the other party to the connection has gone missing.

   A device which transmits via TCP will know that all of its data has been successfully delivered.  A device which is receiving TCP will not know when it has received all data that has been sent to date, unless it receives a packet with a  "FIN" flag, indicating that there will be no further data.

Answer (score 0):

Compare TCP with a phone conversation. You talk to someone and (s)he answers to what you say. You discuss and you check if the other one understood what you were asking.

Compare UDP to leaving a message in the voicemail. You don't know if it was received, neither if your request was granted/executed.

Comment: The phone metaphor for TCP has specifically to do with the way that the caller and the called follow a protocol to establish a connection. What's done with that connection after it's established is after the fact.

Comment: Yes you are right JustJeff. It is about setting up the call, setting up the connection. Check if you're speaking to the right person.